# Tinny sounds from Røde NTG-2

Tags: shotgun, battery

I'm using a Røde NTG-2 shotgun on a mounted boom pole connected to a Nikon Z8. I was recording for 3 days over a 5-day period and on the final day, the recordings from the mic were very tinny sounding and also picked up a lot more background sounds. It almost sounded like the camera's internal mic was recording the sound, but I'm pretty sure the mic was plugged in. The previous days' recordings sound great.

I'm using a standard alkaline battery in the mic, directly connected to the camera—no sound recorder with phantom power because I read that the mic performs better on battery. I checked the battery condition afterwards and it wasn't full power, but definitely seemed to have enough power for recording. I read that the mic will drain the battery if left in the mic, but I left the battery in the mic because it was inconvenient to remove it daily. So the questions are:

Could the mic drain the battery in five days time if I leave the battery in the mic?

If the battery is low or starting to die, would it cause the tinny sound I'm getting? Or is this a different issue?

Also, is there anything that I can use to salvage the recordings I have? The tools in Premiere Pro and Audition don't seem to help.

Comment: I know nothing about the Røde, sorry, but the current 'exciting new toy' to clean up dialog is [Adobe Enhance](https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance) (free for some features but requires sign-up).

Comment: Thank you for the link. That helped recover most of the audio.

Comment: Welcome - sometimes [not always] you can squeeze a bit more out of it by running it a second time.

Comment: It's easy to over-process so I did it minimally. Luckily, I have second sound source where I pumped up the gain (and noise), but the enhance removed the noise and provided a cleaner and clearer soundtrack. Thanks again. This was a career saver.

Comment: Guessing: it could be moisture. All mics are effected but so called RF mics less: Rode NTG3 or some Sennheiser MKH mics.